# Create Django model or update if exists

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create a model object, like Person, if person's id doesn't not exist, or I will get that person object.

The code to create a new person as following:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    objects = PersonManager()

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def create_person(self, identifier):
        person = self.create(identifier = identifier)
        return person
```

But I don't know where to check and get the existing person object.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

If you're looking for "update if exists else create" use case, please refer to [@Zags excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26286864/2800876)

---

Django already has a `get_or_create`, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

For you it could be :

```
id = 'some identifier'
person, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(identifier=id)

if created:
   # means you have created a new person
else:
   # person just refers to the existing one
```

Answer (score 276):

It's unclear whether your question is asking for the [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method (available from at least Django 1.3) or the [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method (new in Django 1.7).  It depends on how you want to update the user object.

Sample use is as follows:

```
# In both cases, the call will get a person object with matching
# identifier or create one if none exists; if a person is created,
# it will be created with name equal to the value in `name`.

# In this case, if the Person already exists, its existing name is preserved
person, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(
        identifier=identifier, defaults={"name": name}
)

# In this case, if the Person already exists, its name is updated
person, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
        identifier=identifier, defaults={"name": name}
)
```

Comment: +1 for `update_or_create` because for that use case it's better than `get_or_create` just to call `save()` on the object again.

Comment: In my case, in place of identifier, i have group of fields which forms unique_together. How is the usage for this case?

Comment: @OmkarDeshpande identifier is just an example; you can pass in any valid django query, such as `Person.objects.get_or_create(a=a, b=b, c=c, defaults={"name": name})`

Comment: What if I want to add more fields to the created Person than the default ones?

Comment: @LoBellin the `defaults` argument to these functions is where you specify what fields you want added to the model.  It has nothing to do with defaults specified on fields of your model

Comment: This is the most correct of the responses I've read. update_or_create is the most common use case.

Answer (score 11):

Django has support for this, check [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

```
person, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(name='abc')
if created:
    # A new person object created
else:
    # person object already exists
```

Answer (score 11):

For only a small amount of objects the **update_or_create** works well, but if you're doing over a large collection it won't scale well. **update_or_create** always first runs a SELECT and thereafter an UPDATE.

```
for the_bar in bars:
    updated_rows = SomeModel.objects.filter(bar=the_bar).update(foo=100)
        if not updated_rows:
            # if not exists, create new
            SomeModel.objects.create(bar=the_bar, foo=100)
```

This will at best only run the first update-query, and only if it matched zero rows run another INSERT-query. Which will greatly increase your performance if you expect most of the rows to actually be existing.

It all comes down to your use case though. If you are expecting mostly inserts then perhaps the [bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) command could be an option.

Answer (score 4):

Thought I'd add an answer since your question title looks like it is asking how to create or update, rather than get or create as described in the question body.

If you did want to create or update an object, the .save() method already has this behaviour by default, from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert):

> Django abstracts the need to use INSERT or UPDATE SQL statements.
> Specifically, when you call save(), Django follows this algorithm:
>
> If the object’s primary key attribute is set to a value that evaluates
> to True (i.e., a value other than None or the empty string), Django
> executes an UPDATE. If the object’s primary key attribute is not set
> or if the UPDATE didn’t update anything, Django executes an INSERT.

It's worth noting that when they say 'if the UPDATE didn't update anything' they are essentially referring to the case where the id you gave the object doesn't already exist in the database.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use update_or_create just like get_or_create and here is the pattern I follow for update_or_create assuming a model Person with id (key), name, age, is_manager as attributes -

```
update_values = {"is_manager": False}
new_values = {"name": "Bob", "age": 25, "is_manager":True}

obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(identifier='id',
                                               defaults=update_values)
if created:
    obj.update(**new_values)
```

Answer (score 1):

If one of the input when you create is a primary key, this will be enough:

```
Person.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
```

It will automatically update if exist since two data with the same primary key is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the answer you are looking for

```
EmployeeInfo.objects.update_or_create(
    #id or any primary key:value to search for
    identifier=your_id, 
    #if found update with the following or save/create if not found
    defaults={'name':'your_name'}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I needed to have the information if the object was updated (for propagation in other systems). I coded this little dirty function :

```py
# Get object, create it if not existing, update it if existing, and return it with created and updated flag.
# pk must be in kwargs, and if creation needed, all required fields must be in kwargs
def get_or_create_or_update(classmodel, pk, **kwargs) -> (object, bool, bool):
    obj = None
    if pk not in kwargs :
        raise Exception(f"Missing pk '{pk}' in kwargs")
    try:
        obj = classmodel.objects.get(**{pk:kwargs[pk]})
    except classmodel.DoesNotExist:
        # TODO check required fields -> In fact, create will raise an error if required fields are missing
        obj = classmodel.objects.create(**kwargs)
        return obj, True, False
    
    updated = False
    for field in classmodel._meta.get_fields():
        if field.name in kwargs and getattr(obj, field.name) != kwargs[field.name] :
            setattr(obj, field.name, kwargs[field.name])
            updated = True
            
    if updated :
        obj.save()
    return obj, False, updated
```