# Django model method - create_or_update

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Similar to [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), I would like to be able to `update_or_create` in Django.

Until now, I have using an approaching similar to how [@Daniel Roseman does it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6382929/1287714). However, I'd like to do this more succinctly as a model method.

[This snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1114/) is quite old and I was wondering if there is a better way to do this in more recent version of Django.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Django model or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115318/create-django-model-or-update-if-exists)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

See [`QuerySet.update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) (new in Django 1.7dev)

Answer (score 142):

There is [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create), eg::

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'first_name': 'Bob'},
)
# If person exists with first_name='John' & last_name='Lennon' then update first_name='Bob'
# Else create new person with first_name='Bob' & last_name='Lennon'
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining what the defaults does. It's super confusing in docs. :D

Comment: @ShahriarRahmanZahin thank you for the kind words. maybe i will submit a pull request in django\

Comment: Best explanation I've seen so far about what the `defaults` does. Not clear in the documentation.