# Post request to external Rest Service using Django - use returned json to update model

Tags: json, django, rest, camunda

I require some advice on the best way to implement the following details using Camunda Rest API and Django:

1) User is presented with a form - Selects the details and then does a POST request to camunda using
'http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/key/Process_B_PerProject/start'

the details sent in this POST request consist of 3 variables in a JSON RAW : in the form of :

```
{"variables":
    {"UserID" : {"value" : "user.", "type": "String"},
     "OrganisationID" : {"value" : "some value", "type": "String"}
    },
     "businessKey" : "SomeBusinessKey"
    }
```

from views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import StartProject

```
 import requests

 class StartProcessView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'startdeliveryphase.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = StartProject()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})





    def post(self,request):
        form = StartProject()
        url = "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/key/Process_B_PerProject/start"
        payload = "{\"variables\":\r\n    {\"Username\" : {\"value\" : \"[form.Username]\", \"type\": \"String\"},\r\n     \"OrganisationInitiating\" : {\"value\" : \"[form.OrganisationInitiator]\", \"type\": \"String\"}},\r\n     \"businessKey\" : {form.businessKey}\r\n    }"
        headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
        return render(response, self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

The response is returned as a 200 along with a JSON payload in the form:

```
 {
    "links": [
        {
            "method": "GET",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-instance/fbff8359-84cd-11ea-a2e1-00155d891509",
                "rel": "self"
            }
        ],
        "id": "fbff8359-84cd-11ea-a2e1-00155d891509",
        "definitionId": "Process_B_PerProject:1:71921815-737c-11ea-91a6-00155d891509",
        "businessKey": "SomeBusinessKey",
        "caseInstanceId": null,
        "ended": false,
        "suspended": false,
        "tenantId": null
}
```

Question 1 - from this part - how do I get the variables from the form into the payload: 
the method I have tried gets a 500 response - so something going wrong here.

Question 2 - what is the method to use the response to update a model?

Comment: how also to create the json from form data in POST request? {
  "variables": {
     "aVariable" : {
         "value" : "aStringValue",
         "type": "String"},
         
     "anotherVariable" : {
     "value" : true,
     "type": "Boolean"}
 },
 
 "businessKey" : "myBusinessKey"
}   _ given that my variables are;  avariable - UserID / another variable -Form_OrganisationID and business key is again another from value businessKey- I have looked at the Jsons dumps - it would require a variable loop as sometimes there may be more than 2 variables and sometimes 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:
Use `response.json()` to get json from response, review [Request doc](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Question 2:
For save use `create or update method` [Create or update django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329946/django-model-method-create-or-update)

Comment: @Edcoenejo - Thank you - I have used the following: - url = "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/key/Process_B_PerProject/start"
        payload = "{\"variables\":\r\n    {\"UserID\" : {\"value\" : \"user.\", \"type\": \"String\"},\r\n     \"OrganisationID\" : {\"value\" : \"some value\", \"type\": \"String\"}\r\n    },\r\n     \"businessKey\" : \"SomeBusinessKey\"\r\n    }"
        headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

Comment: in you payload use a dict not is necessary use a string `payload={'key': 'value'}`

Comment: the format of the json is listed here:[link]( https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/reference/rest/process-definition/post-start-process-instance/#starting-a-process-instance-at-its-default-initial-activity). so for example in the forms.py - I have fields  linked to the model named Form_Field_Business_Key or Form_field_CamundaInstanceID.  In effect, the user enter some data on a form - abd.html - that is then POST to the camunda API - it should return a 200 along with some instance ids; I want to take them instance id's, add them to the form and save it. - spent hrs trying to do something simple

Comment: ive updated this post as ive managed to half implement but getting other issues now : <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394599/json-post-from-django-to-camunda>