# how to update date in django table?

Tags: django, django-views

I created attendance management system and i want that when user enter attendace , if attendance for that date already exist than it only update.

**How to update attendance field in attendance table if data is already exist of that date ?**

**This is my views file**

```
def index(request):

    staffs = staff.objects.all()

    a = staff.objects. values_list('id', flat=True)

    attendances = attendance.objects.all()
    amounts = amount.objects.all()
    
    date = datetime.date.today()
    if request.method == "POST" :
        for i in a :
            print(i)
            stf = 'staff_id' + str(i)
            print(stf)
            atd = 'attendance' + str(i)
            print(atd)
            staff_id = request.POST.get(stf, None)
            attendances = request.POST.get(atd, None)

            date = datetime.date.today()

            ins = attendance(staff_id=staff_id, attendance=attendances, date=date)
            ins.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/index")
    date = datetime.date.today()
    return render(request, "salary/index.html", {'staff': staffs, 'attendance': attendances, 'amount': amounts, 'date': date})
```

**This is my template file where their is form**

```
<form action="/index" method="POST">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            {% for staffs in staff %}
                                                <input type="hidden" name="staff_id{{staffs.id}}" value="{{staffs.id}}">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="attendance{{staffs.id}}" id='input_attendance{{staffs.id}}'>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td> {{staffs.id}} </td>
                                                    <td> {{staffs.name}} </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                                            {% for attendances in attendance %}
                                                                {% if attendances.staff_id|add:0 == staffs.id|add:0 %}
                                                                    {% if attendances.attendance == 'present'%}
                                                                        {% if attendances.date == date %}
                                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id='present{{staffs.id}}'>
                                                                                Present
                                                                            </button>
                                                                        {% else %}
                                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id='present{{staffs.id}}'>
                                                                                Not entered
                                                                            </button>
                                                                        {% endif %}
                                                                    {% elif attendances.attendance == 'absent'%}
                                                                        {% if attendances.date == date %}
                                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id='present{{staffs.id}}'>
                                                                                Absent
                                                                            </button>
                                                                        {% else %}
                                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id='present{{staffs.id}}'>
                                                                                Not entered
                                                                            </button>
                                                                        {% endif %}
                                                                    {% elif attendances.attendance == 'half-day'%}
                                                                        {% if attendances.date == date %}
                                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id='present{{staffs.id}}'>
                                                                                Half-day
                                                                            </button>
                                                                        {% else %}
                                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id='present{{staffs.id}}'>
                                                                                Not entered
                                                                            </button>
                                                                        {% endif %}
                                                                    {% endif %}
                                                                {% endif %}
                                                            {% empty %}
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id='present{{staffs.id}}'>
                                                                    Present
                                                                </button>
                                                            {% endfor %}
                                                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                                                <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="attendance_present({{staffs.id}})">Present</a>
                                                                <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="attendance_absent({{staffs.id}})">Absent</a>
                                                                <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="attendance_half_day({{staffs.id}})">Half-day</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td> {{staffs.role}} </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                
                                            {% endfor %}
                                            <tr>
                                                <button type="submit" style="float:right" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                                            </tr>
                                        </form>
```

**This is my model file**

```
class staff(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    salary = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    
class attendance(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField
    staff_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    attendance = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django model method - create\_or\_update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329946/django-model-method-create-or-update)

Comment: can you provide the code

Comment: Did you read the link I gave you?