# How to perform an update or create in the view using django rest framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a music webapp using django and django rest framework - the problem lies in implementing the listen record counter .Everytime a user plays a song, the counter for that song_id,user_id should increase.

My model looks like this,

```
class Listen_Record(models.Model):
    number=None
    listen_count = models.IntegerField(default=1,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    songid = models.ForeignKey(Song)
```

My view,

```
class ListenRecordCreateAPIView(GenericAPIView,CreateModelMixin,UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = Listen_Record.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListenRecordListSerializer



    def put(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if Listen_Record.objects.filter(user=request.data['user'], songid=request.data['songid']).exists():

            tableid = Listen_Record.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).filter(user=request.data['user'],
                                                                                songid=request.data['songid']).get()
            cnt = None
            try:
                cnt = Listen_Record.objects.get(id=tableid)
                print(cnt)
            except AttributeError:

                cnt.listen_count = 0

            cnt.listen_count += 1
            print(cnt.listen_count)
            cnt.save(['listen_count'])
        return self.update(cnt,*args,**kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if Listen_Record.objects.filter(user=request.data['user'], songid=request.data['songid']).exists():
            self.put(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.create(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Basically, the default method would be to POST, but if userid and songid, exists, it should PUT instead to increment the listen_count field. The error I'm getting now is "UNIQUE constraint failed: api_listen_record.id"

Is there a more elegant way to implement this feature or how to fix the error?

Edit: I get that there is the update_or_create method, but how do i use it in context with post/put method using django rest framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Django model or update if exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115318/create-django-model-or-update-if-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, the default method would be to POST, but if userid and
>   songid, exists, it should PUT instead to increment the listen_count
>   field. The error I'm getting now is "UNIQUE constraint failed:
>   api_listen_record.id"

This is your main problem. The premise is on the client to issue the right request, your job as the API is to validate a request.

If you really want to enforce PUT vs. POST, then if the record exists, and the request is POST, you should reject it:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    filter = Listen_Record.objects.filter(user=request.data['user'],
                                          songid=request.data['songid'])
    if filter.exists():
        raise ValidationError({'error': 'POST not allowed, send PUT'})
    else:
        return self.create(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Similarly, your PUT method should also have such a check:

```
def put(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    try:
       record = Listen_Record.objects.get(user=request.data['user'],
                                          songid=request.data['songid'])
       record.listen_count = record.listen_count + 1
       record.save()
       return self.update(record,*args,**kwargs)
    except Listen_Record.DoesNotExist:
       raise ValidationError({"error": "Send POST not PUT to create records"})
```

Comment: Thanks! It sort of works now but the put request gives an error -  "Expected view ListenRecordCreateAPIView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly." My listen count is still updated though, but would love to get rid of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django's update_or_create method if you are on django 1 dot 7.
Example taken from their docs

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='John', last_name='Lennon', defaults=updated_values)
```

returns the an instance and created where created is decievingly a boolean.

also a dupe of this [Create Django model or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115318/create-django-model-or-update-if-exists)