# Update Object not Duplicate in views.py django

Tags: python, django

this is my code

```
def createstock(request):
    stock = Stock()
    stock.title = 'AAPL'
    stock.div_ammount = '1'
    stock.save()
    return render(request, 'stocks/index.html')
```

Whenever i call this this via URL. It creates the row in the database table. But i want to check that if

> stock.title = 'AAPL'

this title is already in database then dont create object, only update its values. These values will be dynamic in future. But now its hardcore values.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for update_or_create:

- [Django model method - create_or_update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329946/django-model-method-create-or-update)
- [Create Django model or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115318/create-django-model-or-update-if-exists/26286864)

Answer (score 2):

```
def createstock(request):
    stock, created = Stock.objects.update_or_create(title="AAPL", defaults={"div_ammount": "1"})
    return render(request, 'stocks/index.html')
```

Comment: You've got a typo in there: updare

Comment: @Sergey Pugach Why are  you using two variables stock and created. Kindly explain this to me

Comment: @HuZaiFaZahoOr because what `update_or_create` returns is a tuple with 2 variables, one is object itself, updated or created and the second one is bool that means if it was created or taken from DB. In case it was first time created it will return `created` as `True`

Comment: Here some details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create