# how do I properly write django helper functions in order to check for new rows, and if the data was changed?

Tags: python, django, helper

I am trying to write two functions in Django as helpers where it will help me to check if new data is coming or if the existing data was changed for further update

```
is_new_row - will understand if the row is new and add it to an array that will be bulk created

is_data_modified - will look for the row in the old data and understand if the data of that row is changed and will update only if its changed
```

```
old_data = Person.objects.all() 


    for row in api_data:
        if is_new_row(row, old_data):
            new_rows_array.append(row)
        else:
            if is_data_modified(row, old_data):
                ...
                # do the update
            else:
                continue
```

helpers

```
def is_new_row(row, old_data):
    ??

def is_data_modified(row, old_data): 
    ??
```

Comment: how do you recognize when data is new? How do you get these data? Normally new object Person doesn't have `ID/pk` but Django already use this to create new or update data in database and you don't have to do it on your own.

Comment: @furas one approach using `old_data = Person.objects.all()` , but I also I can use some sort of  var, created = get_or_created if its new or not

Comment: at first moment I didn't see that you get data from external `api_data` - but data should have some unique values which never change - ie. `ID` - and then you have to search this `ID` in database and `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. If you can change every field in row then you can change all values in row and you don't know if you should insert as new or replace with other row..

Comment: exactly, but how do I write my helpers to do so? I am just trying to track compare old with new data , and if its new

Comment: as any other query in database `Person.objects.select(id=row.id)` and if you get no result then you have to create new `Person` and `save()` it. If you get result `person` then put new values in this `person` and also use `save()` it.

Comment: BTW: if you first get all rows from database `old_data = Person.objects.all()` then you will have to write own `for`-loop to check all rows in `old_data`. I don't know if it will faster then using database. Django may somehow cache queries and send all updates in one bulk - and searching in database may works faster then with for-loop. And if you will have to update i.e. 2 rows then there is no need to read all rows from database

Comment: [Create Django model or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115318/create-django-model-or-update-if-exists/26286864) and see `get_or_create` which get row from database if it exist (you need some unique value in rows) - and then you can assing new (or all) values and save it. Or it creates empty object and you can also assign all values and save it.